# Clip a circular path of a div with precision (curve path)

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I want to clip my div upper portion as a curve and I used https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ to clip path.
But the curve is not smooth. The curve is not smooth. How to make a smoooooth curve using css?

I have added some pics.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use an SVG mask instead, with an elliptical path drawn.

Comment: this is the job of mask, check the last snippet of the duplicate you will find an example. It's on the bottom but you can easily make it on the top

Comment: Thank you Temani Afif :)